# Multithreading issue while using Mutex in SerialCommunication C++

Tags: windows, multithreading, visual-c++, serial-port, mutex

I am developing a serial communication software using windows functions.
In this CSerialCommhelper is class which handles all the serial communication functions and CphysicalLayer is one which make use of that class.

```
class CSerialCommHelper :
public CCommAgent
 {
    HANDLE m_pPortHandle;           //Handle to the COM port
    HANDLE m_hReadThread;           //Handle to the Read thread
    HANDLE m_hPortMutex;            //Handle to Port Mutex
    std::wstring m_strPortName;     //Portname
    COMMTIMEOUTS m_CommTimeouts;    //Communication Timeout Structure
    _DCB dcb;                       //Device Control Block
    DWORD m_dwThreadID;     //Thread ID

public:
    CSerialCommHelper(CPhysicalLayer *);
    virtual HRESULT Open();
    virtual HRESULT ConfigPort();
    static void * ReadThread(void *);
    virtual HRESULT Write(const unsigned char *,DWORD);
    virtual HRESULT Close();
    //virtual HRESULT Flush(DWORD dwFlag = PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR);
    wstring StringToWstring(const string &);
    ~CSerialCommHelper(void);
};
```

CommAgent is contains a CphysicalLayer pointer for notify the physicalLayer when data is received.

```
HRESULT CSerialCommHelper::Write(const unsigned char *pucDataToWrite,DWORD ulLength)
{
    unsigned long  bytesWritten=0, ij = 0;
    WaitForSingleObject(m_hPortMutex,INFINITE);
    if(WriteFile(m_pPortHandle,pucDataToWrite,ulLength,&bytesWritten,NULL))
    {
    if(!ReleaseMutex(m_hPortMutex))
    {
        DWORD err=GetLastError();

        // Mutex released succesfully..
    }
    }
    if (bytesWritten != ulLength)
            return E_FAIL;
    return S_OK;

}
void * CSerialCommHelper::ReadThread(void * pObj)
{
    CSerialCommHelper *pCSerialCommHelper =(CSerialCommHelper *)pObj; 
    DWORD dwBytesTransferred = 0;
    unsigned char byte = 0;

    while (pCSerialCommHelper->m_pPortHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        pCSerialCommHelper->m_strBuffer.clear();
        pCSerialCommHelper->m_usBufSize=0;
        WaitForSingleObject(pCSerialCommHelper->m_hPortMutex,INFINITE);
        do
        {
            dwBytesTransferred = 0;
            ReadFile (pCSerialCommHelper->m_pPortHandle, &byte, 1, &dwBytesTransferred, 0);
            if (dwBytesTransferred == 1)
            {
                pCSerialCommHelper->m_strBuffer.push_back(byte);
                pCSerialCommHelper->m_usBufSize++;
                continue;

            }
        }
        while (dwBytesTransferred == 1);
        if(pCSerialCommHelper->m_usBufSize!=0)
        {
            CProtocolPacket *pCProtocolPacket = new CProtocolPacket(0,2048);
            pCProtocolPacket->AddBody(pCSerialCommHelper->m_usBufSize,(unsigned char*)pCSerialCommHelper->m_strBuffer.c_str());
            pCSerialCommHelper->m_pCPhysicalLayer->Data_ind(pCProtocolPacket);
            delete pCProtocolPacket;
        }
            ReleaseMutex(pCSerialCommHelper->m_hPortMutex);
        Sleep(2);
    }
    ExitThread(0);


    return 0;
}
```

This is how i am creating file and mutex

```
    m_pPortHandle = CreateFile(m_strPortName.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
                         OPEN_EXISTING,NULL, NULL );
if (m_pPortHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)

    {
        return E_HANDLE;
        //throw failure
    }

m_hPortMutex = CreateMutex(NULL,TRUE,L"MY_MUTEX");


if( m_hReadThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ReadThread,(LPVOID)this,0,&m_dwThreadID))
{
}
else
{
    return E_FAIL;
}
return S_OK;
```

But after writing a string to the port the write function is releasing mutex successfully, but read thread is still waiting.

Comment: Why are you protecting a bidirectional port, with independent tx and rx channels, with a mutex?  Also, 'Sleep(2);' :((

Comment: Also, reading one byte at a time with a system call :((

Comment: This software is used for sending commands to a device.  After sending one command PC must wait for the response. In order to protect any one from writing to port before the response is received , i am using Mutex.

Comment: Hmm... suggestion.. if the protocol is always request/response, maybe it would be easier to queue 'RequestResponse' class instances, with members that can hold/generate the request and parse the reply, to one thread that both sends the response and then waits for the reply?

Comment: Sleep(2) is not required . i wrote just for debugging. :)

Comment: Anyway, the rx thread definitely gets stuck on the WaitForSingleObject for the mutex?  It never reaches the next line?

Comment: Oh wait - you are naming the mutex.  Not sure of the lifetime of a named mutex.  Need to check.  Usually, inter-thread comms mutexes are not named.

Comment: @Martin James That's a good suggestion . Thank you.:)

Comment: Yes, That is the problem . Once the write function is executed, then the read thread is getting stuck on the WaitForSingleObject.

Comment: Oh - do you still have a problem, or is it fixed?

Comment: Yes, I still have problem.

Comment: Is there a reason for the mutex to be initially owned by the thread creator (and does it get released)?

Comment: @Hasturkun No there is no specific reason. I tried making the mutex with intial owner as null, in both cases mutex is not getting released.

Comment: Just to clarify, we're talking about setting the second argument to be `FALSE` instead of `TRUE`, correct? Also, are you sure that the write succeeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with Readfile function in ReadThread .It is not returning properly.
I don't know the reason.

```
void * CSerialCommHelper::ReadThread(void * pObj)
{
    CSerialCommHelper *pCSerialCommHelper =(CSerialCommHelper *)pObj; 
    DWORD dwBytesTransferred =0;
    char byte[1];
    string buffer;

    while (pCSerialCommHelper->m_pPortHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {

        WaitForSingleObject(pCSerialCommHelper->m_hPortMutex,INFINITE);
        do
        {
           dwBytesTransferred = 0;
                bool bReadResult= false;

                 bReadResult = ReadFile (pCSerialCommHelper->m_pPortHandle,byte,1,&dwBytesTransferred,NULL);


                if (dwBytesTransferred == 1)
                {
                    buffer.push_back(byte[0]);
                    continue;

                }


        }
        while (dwBytesTransferred == 1);

            pCSerialCommHelper->m_pCPhysicalLayer->Data_ind((unsigned char *)buffer.c_str());
            ReleaseMutex(pCSerialCommHelper->m_hPortMutex);

    }
    ExitThread(0);


    return 0;
}
```

I tried replacing the code with this snippet and found that bReadResult is not getting updated properly.

Comment: The Problem was COMMTIMOUT structure elements was not set properly. After setting that code is working properly.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the mutex, you set the *bInitialOwner* argument to TRUE. So at this point the mutex is owned by the main thread.

```
m_hPortMutex = CreateMutex(NULL,TRUE,L"MY_MUTEX");
```

You then create a `ReadThread` which attempts to acquire the mutex. This is obviously going to block until the main thread releases it.

```
WaitForSingleObject(pCSerialCommHelper->m_hPortMutex,INFINITE);
```

When the main thread attempts to write something, the first thing it does is attempt to acquire the mutex again.

```
WaitForSingleObject(m_hPortMutex,INFINITE);
```

Since the main thread already owns the mutex, this call will return immediately without blocking, but at this stage you've now acquired the mutex twice in the main thread (once in the `CreateMutex` call and a second time with `WaitForSingleObject`).

When you're finished writing to the file, you then release the mutex with this call:

```
if(!ReleaseMutex(m_hPortMutex))
```

But that only releases it once, so it's still owned by the main thread and the read thread will continue to block.

The bottom line is that you should set the *bInitialOwner* parameter to FALSE when creating the mutex.

```
m_hPortMutex = CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,L"MY_MUTEX");
```

Quoting the [CreateMutex documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The thread that owns a mutex can specify the same mutex in repeated wait function calls without blocking its execution. [...] However, to release its ownership, the thread must call ReleaseMutex once for each time that the mutex satisfied a wait.

Comment: I have updated the changes as per your answer. But now the write function is not able to acquire the mutex. :(

Comment: WaitforSingleobject() would be able to acquire the mutex since it is not  owned by anyone , right? But it is not able to do that !

Comment: It should be able to unless the `ReadThread` has already acquired the mutex and is blocked before it calls `ReleaseMutex`. Pause the code in your debugger and see what the `ReadThread` is doing.

Comment: I debugged the code , i found that , readThread is executing only upto Readfile(). After that it is going to write() in main thread   and getting stuck there...

Comment: I tried commenting Readfile() , then everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, I see the following problems:

- The mutex is initially owned by the thread that called the constructor.
- `Write()` doesn't release the mutex on error.

I'm guessing that you call `Write()` from the same thread as the constructor call, which works because it already owns the mutex. After this, the mutex is still owned by the thread. making the other thread block.

I'd recommend that you move the release call outside of the check on whether the write suceeded (as you always need to release it).

You should note that you need to call `ReleaseMutex()` once for each time you acquire the mutex, by [`CreateMutex()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `bInitialOwner` set to `TRUE`, or by a successful `WaitForSingleObject()` call on the mutex.

Comment: I debugged the code line by line, and found the  ReleaseMutex() function is getting executed successfully. Then also thread was not able to get ownership of mutex.

Comment: Is there a `ReleaseMutex()` call after your `CreateMutex()` call? your arguments specify that the mutex should be acquired.

Comment: No, I wrote the code for debugging purpose. I am removing it.

Comment: @kernel Hasturkun is correct. The main problem is calling CreateMutex with TRUE - I've tried to explain in more detail in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17277842/2334192).

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the mutex with no name.  Named mutexes are normally used for inter-process comms.  Typically, a mutex used for comms between threads within a process are not named - they do not need to be opened by name because the mutex handle is acessible by all the process threads.